# Calling another script file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, call

I am having a problem with calling another script from within a script. 
I run a script "a.m" and it uses a function detailed in another script "b.m", and within "b.m" there is an if clause which is supposed to rerun "a.m" given a certain condition is fulfilled. However, when trying to write this if clause and calling "a.m", i get this error:

Undefined variable "a" or class "a.m".

```
% My "if" clause in b.m looks like this:
if numel(xyz) == 0
    a.m;
end
```

Why am I getting this error, considering it's "a.m" that I initially run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. You call it as `a` not `a.m`.